# Is natural and correct to say "something passed over me" meaning it didn't affect me in any way?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is natural and correct to say *something passed over me* meaning it didn't affect me in any way? For example:

> The economic crisis **passed over** me. I didn't lose my job.

If doesn't sound good, could you tell me what you would say to communicate it.

Comment: Passed me by, or past by me.

Comment: @BruceMurray is past by me a typo?

Comment: Yes. I'm on a phone with predictive text.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Using **over** is not incorrect. There are variants which use **over** such as "I was passed over for promotion" and "the remark passed over his head."

Comment: I can't help thinking there's something of a "subject inversion" going on here. It's not so much that *the **crisis** passed **me** by* (even though that's how we normally phrase it). Rather it's that ***I passed by** the crisis* (without really noticing and/or being affected by it). It feels a bit like [“The ticket is printing” vs “…is being printed”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5725/) to me, but I don't actually know if it really is an example of [The Middle Construction](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/48542426.pdf).

Comment: I was passed over for promotion vs the promotion passed me over.  Hmmm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are common ways of expressing that someone was *not* affected by an event or circumstance:

*The economic crisis bypassed me*

*The economic crisis passed me by.*

*The economic crisis passed by me.*

"Over" is more likely to suggest that a person was affected:

*The crisis was over my family for many months.* (We felt its effect)

*A wave of regret passed over me.* (I felt intense regret)